# Magento is caching 404 URLs so that they return "200 OK" status instead of "404 not found". How do I prevent this?

Tags: apache, oop, magento

I'm running Magento Enterprise 1.9 with APC caching on Apache (Debian).

If I browse to a non-existent URL on my site, I receive a 404 response from the server and am presented with my 404 page as expected. However, if I then visit that same URL *again*, this time (and all subsequent times) I receive a "200 OK" status from the server, despite the URL still being invalid and the 404 page still being presented.

Examples:

```
$ curl -I http://www.example.com/some-nonexistent-URL
$ HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

$ curl -I http://www.example.com/some-nonexistent-URL
$ HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I am *assuming* that this is because the resposne to that URL is being cached somehow so the server sends out a "200 OK" cached version of the 404 page (!).

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was Magento's Full Page Cache fault.

I discovered Magento checks for the presence of a cookie called `NO_CACHE`, so I just put `$_COOKE["NO_CACHE"] = true;` at the point before the 404 action is called (in my case, `/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php`).

I also added a `cache-control: no-cache, must revalidate` header, and the same cookie as above into the 404 page template itself for good measure.